# What are the tips when posting a node to drupal remotely using Rest server and json

Tags: json, rest, drupal, drupal-7, remote-access

I want to connect remotely to Drupal using Rest server .
the my first Question is what resources should I choose to post and update nodes remotely.
Second question is how should fields posted using JSON in drupal 7
and last question is about authentication , should i have to do it in client side or Drupal will done it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create a REST server I would recommend the services module http://drupal.org/project/services it allows node access and creation over the REST API.
Authentication can be integrated with OAUTH on the serverside